# Check one table values with another and then insert to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

have 2 tables for example lets call one - **names** , second - **age**

```
names table :                   age table :
ID      Names               ID      Names    Age
1       Bob                  1      Bob      18
2       Tommy                2      Tommy    21
3       Kate                 3      Kate     20
4       Adam                 4      Adam     23
5       Karl                 5      Karl     25
```

in stored procedure want check if name from names table exists in age table

```
create table #tbl
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  age int
)

insert into #tbl (age) values(and hear each age for each name)
```

I think i need some loop for doing it without cursor but how ? please help me

**EDIT**

I solve it like :

```
create table #tbl 
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  age int
);

INSERT INTO #tbl (age) 
SELECT a.age
  FROM age a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT n.name
   FROM names n
   WHERE a.Name = n.Name)

   select * from #tbl
```

Comment: Its not very clear from your question, but are you trying to ensure that only names that exist in the names table get inserted into the age table?

Comment: Why do you have two tables for this?

Comment: @GSerg it's for example

Comment: @user2801943 Then it's not a good example, because it's quite unobvious. When tables are designed properly, you can immediately see what the relation is. With your tables, there is e.g. no way to know why you have `Name` column in both, so the relationship between these table is not clear.

Comment: What's this code gotta do with _check if name from names table exists in age table_?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
create table #tbl 
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  age int
);

INSERT INTO #tbl (age) 
SELECT a.age
FROM age a
LEFT JOIN names N ON N.Name = A.Name
WHERE N.Name IS NULL

select * from #tbl
```